# Getting bad_alloc error

Tags: c++, arrays

i've been working on my word search algorithm. It works perfectly, but then i decided to test in on really large puzzle like 10000 x 10000 its a matrix filled with symbols. So created a little program which made that puzzle. And then i ran word search it crashed with bad_alloc. 
I use 2D arrays. 
Code:

```
        string ** Matrix = new string*[Height];

        for(int i = 0; i < Height; ++i)
        {
            Matrix[i] = new string[Widht];
        }
```

Height = Widht = 10000;

And i don't know why is it. I have read that new doesn't really have limits so why it crashes?

By the way just for fun i opened windows task manager while program trys to allocate memory and memory goes up to 2m+ and then it crashes.

Comment: You're leaking memory, that's it. Actually, if you get the size of your matrix, and multiply by the size of string(i.e. Height*Width*sizeof(string), i think the OS won't let you allocate that amount of memory

Comment: Do you mean "memory goes up to 2m+" or 2G. Calculate how much memory you think that array should take

Comment: Don’t use task manager. Do use `std::vector`. There shouldn’t be problems allocating 800,000,000/1,600,000,000 bytes on a decent computer unless you have a lot of programs opened.

Comment: Ensure your compiler is generating a 64-bit executable.

Comment: Mark, i mean that in task manager next to processes it shows user name, cpu and memory and it goes up to 2.000.000+ K

Comment: BTW, it's "width", not "widht".

Comment: I know, but i thought eh will be K :D MarkB how should i do that?

Comment: @iCoRe: For VS, use the configuration manager (but, it's not supported if you only have the express version).  However, you can simply reduce your problem size to 1000 x 1000 (which is still pretty large) and have it work fine on 32-bit systems.

Comment: @MarkB I use CB and i really want to make it work even on larger files

Answer (score 6):

The std::string class is 28 bytes for just the class object in the Debug build.  Not counting any storage required for the actual string.  Your program therefore allocates 10000 x 10000 x 28 = 2.8 gigabytes.  A 32-bit process in Windows cannot allocate more than 2 gigabytes, give or take, you are well past that limit.

You'll need write smarter code or switch to 64-bit code generation.  An obvious way to get ahead is to realize that a word-search program only needs a single character per cell, not an entire string.  A `char` will thus be enough.   Or store an entire row of the grid into a single std::string.  Reduces your memory requirements by an easy two orders of magnitude.